# Sent data always null in Asp.Net MVC application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, typescript

To send request i use `jquery` and my javascript method looks like:

```
const documentt = document.getElementById("location-id");
let location: string = "";

if (documentt) {
    location = documentt.innerText;
}

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    data: location,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
```

My controller looks like:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public string GetAvailablePlaces(string param)
 {

 }
```

param is always `null` i've tried to change datatype to `object` - resultless also tried to add `[FromBody]` and it didn't work too.

Please tell what can i do in this case ?

Comment: Are you sure that you element with id `location-id` exists?

Comment: @dganenco 100% exists, I check location value each time while debugging.

Comment: It's smth strange, I've tried to reproduce your problem and was unable to do this. Here the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dganenco/pks5cmyh/)

Comment: @dganenco on frontend I have no one problem, problem somewhere on backend.

Comment: You're sending an object with a property called location, but the server expects a single string (called param, not location). There's a mismatch between those two things. It's not magic, the server cannot guess your intentions, the two ends must match up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise you to change `location` type from string to `Object` in `data` property and then in your controller you should get as param this object's name. Smth like this:

```
.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    data: {location}, //it means object {location:'location'} thanks to desctruction
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});



 [HttpGet]
 public string GetAvailablePlaces(string location)
 {

 }
```